# 3-way ANOVA for reshaped data in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have just discovered reshaping in R and am unsure of how to proceed with an ANOVA once the data is reshaped. I found [this site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/reshape.htm) which has the data organized in a way very similar to my own data. If I were using this hypothetical data, how would I conduct a 3-way ANOVA say between race, program and subject? Now that the subjects have been reshaped into a single column I'm having trouble seeing how to include this variable using the typical ANOVA code. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data are in 'long format' and 'score' is your dependent variable you could do something like:

```
mymodel = aov(score ~ prog + race + subj, data=l)
summary(my model)
```

Which in this case yields:

```
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
prog          1   2864    2864   31.32 2.82e-08 ***
race          1   5064    5064   55.39 2.14e-13 ***
subj          4    106      27    0.29    0.885    
Residuals   993  90780      91                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

n.b. this model contains only the main effects

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I was over-complicating it in my head. What if there were another dependent variable other than score that we wanted to predict using program, race and subject? ex. GPA or ACT score

Comment: Just substitute 'score' for the relevant variable name in the formula above.

Comment: This won't work for my variable, it is a continuous measure that exists as it's own column. When I simply substitute it for 'score' the ANOVA doesn't work correctly. I think that I am incorrect in thinking I can use an ANOVA for this part of the analysis, I will need to look at a multilevel  approach instead.